# where if oracle sql clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have got the following query

```
    select
    Case
    -- Here 
    When count(distinct g.mobile_no) > 0 Then con.IR_BILLING_GROUP_CODE = bil.billing_group_code Else g.mobile_no END mobile_no,     
    cu.customer_no, bil.billing_group_code bil
from customers cu
  inner join billings bil on bil.code = cu.code
  inner join mobile_no g on g.mobile_no = bil.mobile_no
  inner join billing_group con on con.code = bil.code
```

Where it says "Here" above I want to add the following restriction. If from the retrieved mobile numbers there are duplicates (which will be because there are different billing groups in the column bill for the same numbers) then I want to add the restriction con.IR_BILLING_GROUP_CODE = bil.billing_group_code which will return only the relevant billing group and thus the wrong duplicate mobile numbers won't be displayed? The code above says missing keyword?

Example

```
  Customer    Mobile No    Bil
  123         01243473     02
  123         05532234     02
  123         05532234     05
```

So because 05532234 has duplicate due to different billing groups then I need to filter on the column bil. If I add the restriction 
con.IR_BILLING_GROUP_CODE = bil.billing_group_code then either bil = 02 or bil = 05 so that I would know which is the correct billing group for the number 05532234. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: You tagged your question with `mysql` *and* `oracle`, yet the title only mentions `oracle`. So what are you using?

Comment: Well I use Oracle but I guess the query will be the same for both mysql and oracle

Comment: @user3793865 Please don't guess - if your question is only about Oracle, stick to the `Oracle` and `SQL` tags.

Comment: As @bitmagier pointed out in his answer, the `Then con.IR_BILLING_GROUP_CODE = bil.billing_group_code` is wrong. From your description, I gather you're trying to filter somehow on the billing group, but it's not very clear what you want to achieve. Could you add sample input and output to your question (by using the *edit* button) ?

Comment: I have added an exaple

Comment: Do customers without duplicates also have billing groups?  If so, you could just add it to your where clause

Comment: That's the thing. I want to apply the where clause only for the duplicates not for all of them because otherwise I may lose information

Comment: In other words, if there are no duplicates and I add the restriction con.IR_BILLING_GROUP_CODE = bil.billing_group_code then I will lose some of the numbers which don't have duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot place a where clause criteria in your select list. You also cannot use an aggregate function (COUNT) along with non-aggregated columns without grouping.

You can add row numbers to your records per customer and bill where the best match (con.ir_billing_group_code = bil.billing_group_code) comes first. Then filter your result such as to get only the best matching rows, i.e. only row numbers 1.

```
select customer_no, bil, mobile_no
from
(
  select
    cu.customer_no, bil.billing_group_code bil, g.mobile_no,
    row_number over (partition by cu.customer_no, bil.billing_group_code
                     order by 
                       case when con.ir_billing_group_code = bil.billing_group_code
                         then 0 
                         else 1 
                       end
                    ) as rn
  from customers cu
  inner join billings bil on bil.code = cu.code
  inner join mobile_no g on g.mobile_no = bil.mobile_no
  inner join billing_group con on con.code = bil.code
)
where rn = 1;
```